# 3DTouch UIPreviewAction: performseguewithidentifier not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have some peek UIPreviewActions implemented in my iOS Swift app. However, these actions perform segue transactions, which are being ignored. How can I accomplish that?

There is a similar question, but in Objective-C: [UIPreviewAction to Mail From Peek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997288/uipreviewaction-to-mail-from-peek)

```
override func previewActionItems() -> [UIPreviewActionItem] {
    let performSegueAction = UIPreviewAction(title: "Go To View", style: .Default) { (action, viewController) -> Void in
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueID", sender: self)
    }
    return [performSegueAction]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply, but ran into this myself recently so posting the answer in case someone else finds it useful...

At the time the handler in your `UIPreviewAction` is called, view controller is already removed from hierarchy so performing segues has no effect. Instead you should do something like:

```
class PreviewViewController: UIViewController {

var performAction: (() -> Void)?

override func previewActionItems() -> [UIPreviewActionItem] {
    let performSegueAction = UIPreviewAction(title: "Go To View", style: .Default) { (action, viewController) -> Void in
        self.performAction?()
    }
    return [performSegueAction]
}
```

And in parent controller (from which you launch preview):

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? PreviewViewController {
        vc.handleAction = {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueID", sender: self)
        }
    }
    inject(toController: segue.destination)
}
```